# In Razor Pages with Visual Studio 2019, editing a tag attribute will scramble all tag helper attribute values

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages, visual-studio-2019

I'm making a web application using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and trying out Razor Pages more or less for the first time. When using "asp-for" attributes in order to bind an HTML input to a PageModel property, everything works just fine, but then when editing any attribute in any HTML element in the script that **also** has an "asp-for" attribute defined, all "asp-for" values **for every other element but the one I'm editing** are scrambled/wiped out.

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and all extensions are up to date. ASP.NET Core 2.2 and all included packages are their respective latest stable versions.

I've tried disabling all extensions one by one, restarting the application each time to see if one of them is causing any strange behaviour- I'm not using many to begin with though, mostly just GitHub integration and "Format on Save" at the moment.

I've also tried going through the preferences and unchecking many of the validation options for HTML and C#, and things like automatic quotations for new attributes and closing bracket insertions... basically, anything that I thought could potentially have an impact. Nothing has worked.

An example would be something like:

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Entry ID:</td>
            <td><input type="text" asp-for="EntryID" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Entry Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" asp-for="EntryName" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When editing any of the attributes for any element with an **asp-for** attached, the **asp-for** value for the other tags will be scrambled. This happens both when I use the backspace key or the delete key, so it doesn't appear to be keyboard-shortcut related.

Here's a gif of the issue (not enough reputation to post images apparently- apologies).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1gZSvGrQ8ehpTNwKOA2YbCkfLhx_o-M

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be quite grateful. This is really killing productivity and I haven't really come up with any ways to consistently get around the issue- usually when deleting the entire attribute all at once (which still scrambles other values), I can hit Undo once and it'll undo the scrambling but not the deletion itself. That's not 100% though, so it's just a big headache all around.

**UPDATE 7/31**: I've gone ahead and reported this to Microsoft as per Peter B's suggestion. A link to the report can be had [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/669240/razor-pages-html-tag-attribute-values-scrambled-wh.html) if anyone comes along with the same issue and are wondering at the progress there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gif shows it happening for the `id` attribute, but you shouldn't try to specify the **`id`** because the Input Tag Helper already does it for you:

> The Input Tag Helper:
>   
>   * Generates the `id` and `name` HTML attributes for the expression name specified in the `asp-for` attribute. [...]

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I agree that it seems to be acting a bit weird. If it persists, you can try reporting the weird behaviour, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I'm aware, it was just an easy example and happens with any attribute identically. Thanks though, I'll go ahead and report it.

Comment: Reported the problem (appended the question with a link to the report), and they apparently fixed it and will be releasing the fix in an upcoming version. Thanks again for the help, I'll go ahead and mark this answer as accepted.